# Checkmarx and angular2 template xss warning

Tags: angular, dom, xss, checkmarx, secure-coding

I'm facing the follow warning at checkmarx report. I tried to use sanitized pipe to fix but still returning the warning. Any suggestions?

[image: checkmark report]

Comment: the code is in the image: <select [ngModel]="selectedEqpFilterType"...

Comment: and can you provide a sample stackblitz?

Comment: @AakashGarg {{dataType of displayTypes}} => displayTypes is string[]

Comment: Have you tried injecting the sanitiser into your component and using a getter or method to retrieve your html?

Comment: @BenBrookes same issue

Comment: Are you sure? If the variables from your template was sanitised HTML then checkmarx wouldn't pick this issue up as the sanitiseHTML pipe wouldn't need to be used.

Comment: @BenBrookes https://imgur.com/Viy0KVi same error in same case

Comment: Does this still occur if you bind the value to `[innerHtml]` ?

Comment: Let me try. But only the variable or with sanitize method? I will try both...

Comment: @BenBrookes same error: https://imgur.com/BtONgp4

Comment: We will add it to false positives. Thx @BenBrookes!

Answer (score 0):

I add it to False positive! I will use [innerHTML] attribute from angular to show the values.